# Browser Back Button Issue, tries previous request made

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building an asp.net web application. Now, I am facing a strange problem. Whenever, I click on the back button of browser, it take me to the previous request made by the page like if i submitted a form previously, it would try to submit this info again. I don't want this to happen rather, I want to navigate to the previous page. I would be very thankful if someone could suggest me a solution. 
Thanks

Comment: please share your code, framework, screen shots, and details of your solution. What you've offered is vague at best.

Answer (score 0):

After posting on the previous page you can use `Response.Redirect` to go to next page. It should prevent posting again when you come back to the page.

Comment: Is there anything else possible, I am trying to avoid this solution.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to avoid this? This is a common practice.

Comment: Well, the thing is for some pages, there is no particular page where I should redirect it after the form submission.

Comment: Then you can still do Response.Redirect to that page itself.

Comment: It looks like for now I need to stick with Response.Redirect :)

Comment: It's a pretty common pattern for this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

He is talking about the behaviour when the user hits the Browser "Back" button, so suggesting Response.Redirect is meaningless. What is happening is standard browser behaviour for a FORM resubmission: -

[Prevent Form Resubmission in ASP.Net (without redirecting to myself)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761382/prevent-form-resubmission-in-asp-net-without-redirecting-to-myself)

Comment: There should have been a post before, otherwise browser would not want to post again on going back.

Comment: Your answer should be an answer, not a comment on another answer. I would have marked you down if it wasn't for the fact the link is quite useful, although does suggest exactly what was posted here.