# Asp.net c# Page resubmission

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some problem that when I save button show the JavaScript message saved but when next time browser refresh button click its automatically redirect save button work.

Remember this things that when I press save button its show message box in JavaScript message and then page redirect this own page.

Comment: Let's start with some code. Please post some.

Comment: without code you'll get downvotes

Comment: google  "avoid page resubmit"

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to do a Response.Redirect("samepage") from your server side submit button event after processing your request. and pass parameter in the query string. or go to save the value in viewstate.

you can check this answer here to prevent form from re-submission :

[Prevent Form Resubmission in ASP.Net (without redirecting to myself)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761382/prevent-form-resubmission-in-asp-net-without-redirecting-to-myself)